# Hive ADD JAR on HDP sandbox

Tags: xml, hadoop, jar, hive

I have a need to store the XML in HDFS and create hive table on top of that HDFS folder. I have been trying to use the one provided in this [link](https://github.com/dvasilen/Hive-XML-SerDe/wiki/XML-data-sources)

I have added the serde jar to hive after downloading from the [link](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml%22%20AND%20a%3A%22hivexmlserde%22) using the Add jar command.

> ADD JAR hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar

I also got the message saying "Added ... to the classpath"

list jars also confirmed that. But when i try to create the table as mentioned in the same [link](https://github.com/dvasilen/Hive-XML-SerDe/wiki/XML-data-sources) , its failed with the following message

> FAILED: SemanticExcepton cannot find class
>   com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat

Kindly help.

Note: I use HDP 2.3

Attached is the screenshot of the result.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving right permissions and ownership to the jar and then running the ADD command worked. I am not sure why it works that way though!!!

Answer (score 1):

I am able to create the table on HDP 2.3 sandbox. I understand the problem. add jar and list jar success need not mean that jar is available for you.

Follow these steps:

```
Login to the terminal
cd to the path where your jar file is
ls -ltr hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar
Launch hive cli and perform following
hive> add jar hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar;
Added [hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar] to class path
Added resources: [hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar]
hive> CREATE TABLE xml_bank(customer_id STRING, income BIGINT, demographics map<string,string>, financial map<string,string>)
    > ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
    > WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    > "column.xpath.customer_id"="/record/@customer_id",
    > "column.xpath.income"="/record/income/text()",
    > "column.xpath.demographics"="/record/demographics/*",
    > "column.xpath.financial"="/record/financial/*"
    > )
    > STORED AS
    > INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
    > OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
    > TBLPROPERTIES (
    > "xmlinput.start"="<record customer",
    > "xmlinput.end"="</record>"
    > );
OK
Time taken: 2.042 seconds
hive> select * from xml_bank;
OK
Time taken: 0.801 seconds
```

Comment: Hi Durga, I have added the screenshot

Comment: Can you try on a terminal directly instead of through browser?

Comment: Added steps, I understood where the problem is. add jar and list jar can be successful even though there are no jar files registered.

Comment: The issue remains even if i run from the terminal

Comment: I have edited the answer with elaborate steps. I was able to reproduce the error. Try giving absolute path of the jar file eg: `add jar /home/hduser/hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar;` Before running it make sure you have file by running `ls -ltr /home/hduser/hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98627/discussion-between-manikandankannan-and-durga-viswanath-gadiraju).